# Multiple imputation for longitudinal data with 2l.pan or panImpute (mice package in R)

Tags: r, imputation, panel-data, r-mice, multilevel-analysis

I have a longitudinal (panel) data frame called `tradep_red` in long format that contains 200 countries (`country`), 26 years (`year`), the continuous dependent variable `gini` and 2 continuous predictor variables (`trade` and `unempl`, in reality there are 13 but I reduced it to 2 for the sake of this question). Both `gini` and the predictor variables contain missing values. Dummy data is shown below:

```
# Generate dummy data 
set.seed(12345)
country <- as.factor(rep(1:200, each = 26))
year <- rep(1:26, times = 200)
gini <- rnorm(n = 200*26, mean = 20, sd = 4)
trade <- rnorm(n = 200*26, mean = 1000, sd = 7)
unempl <- rnorm(n = 200*26, mean = 4, sd = 0.2)

# Add NA values 
missing_indices_gini <- sample(1:length(gini), 1000)
gini[missing_indices_gini] <- NA
missing_indices_trade <- sample(1:length(trade), 800)
trade[missing_indices_trade] <- NA
missing_indices_unempl <- sample(1:length(unempl), 900)
unempl[missing_indices_unempl] <- NA

# Combine into dataframe
tradep_red <- data.frame(country, year, gini, trade, unempl)
head(tradep_red)
##   country year     gini     trade   unempl
## 1       1    1 22.34212 1006.3982 3.740346
## 2       1    2 22.83786  997.7583 3.801918
## 3       1    3 19.56279  996.9160 3.699202
## 4       1    4       NA        NA 3.838534
## 5       1    5 22.42355  996.0563 3.835563
## 6       1    6       NA 1005.5007 4.115319
```

I want to multiple impute the missing values in the data while specifically accounting for the multilevel structure in the data (i.e. clustering by `country`). With the code below (using the `mice` package), I have been able to create imputed data sets with the `pmm` method.

```
library(mice)

# Multiple imputation
predictorMatrix <- quickpred(tradep_red, 
                             include = c("country", "gini", "trade", "unempl"), 
                             exclude = c("year"), mincor = 0.1)

imp <- mice(data = tradep_red, 
            m = 3, 
            maxit = 5, 
            method = "pmm", 
            predictorMatrix = predictorMatrix,  
            seed = 123)
```

However, I would like to use the `2l.pan` method (or another method such as `panImpute`) to account for the cluster variable `country`. The `2l.pan` method requires a cluster variable to be specified in the `predictorMatrix` by giving `country` a value of `-2`, and then running the imputation:

```
predictorMatrix["country", ] <- -2 # specify country as cluster variable

imp <- mice(data = tradep_red, 
            m = 3, 
            maxit = 5, 
            method = "2l.pan", 
            predictorMatrix = predictorMatrix,  
            seed = 123)
```

This however gives the error:

```
## iter imp variable
##  1   1  giniError in mice.impute.2l.pan(y = c(22.3421152713754, 22.8378640700381,  : 
##  No class variable
```

Alternatively, the cluster variable can be specified in a `formula` statement with the `|` operator. Moreover, the formula statement is required to be a `list`. I have not succeeded in correctly specifying this formula statement. The code below shows what I have tried:

```
formula_imp <- list(gini + trade + unempl ~ (1 | country))

imp <- mice(data = tradep_red, 
            m = 3, 
            maxit = 5, 
            method = "2l.pan", 
            predictorMatrix = predictorMatrix, 
            formulas = formula_imp, 
            seed = 123)
```

This gives the error:

```
## iter imp variable
##  1   1  gini trade unempl  giniError in mice.impute.2l.pan(y = c(22.3421152713754, 22.8378640700381,  : 
##  No class variable
## In addition: Warning messages:
## 1: In Ops.factor(1, country) : ‘|’ not meaningful for factors
## 2: In Ops.factor(1, country) : ‘|’ not meaningful for factors
## 3: In Ops.factor(1, country) : ‘|’ not meaningful for factors
```

I get similar errors when trying to use the alternative `panImpute` method in the `mice` function. How can I correctly specify `country` to be the cluster variable for the multiple imputation process? Any help or references are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The `class` variable needs to be integer. Thus add the following and your first attempt with the `predictorMatrix` will work

```
tradep_red = tradep_red %>% mutate(country = country %>% as.integer() )
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a 100% sure, but I think the specification needs to be changed so that country is the predictor variable for all target (row) variables when you are specifying cluster.

```
predictorMatrix[,"country"] <- -2
```